# Static & Dynamic Section Modelling using Enum & Struct - Swift 4

Tags: swift, struct, enums, data-modeling, sections

I have the following model structure:

```
enum ProductSectionType {
    case ProductDetails
    case ProductPricing
}

enum Item {
    case Brand
    case Collection
    case Dimensions
    case SoldBy
    case Category
    case Pricing
}

struct ProductSection {
    var type: ProductSectionType
    var items: [Item]
}
```

The problem is, case Pricing in enum Item is actually an array.  This is my returned data from my Back End:

```
Product(productCode: "SomeCode",
productBrand: "SomeBrand",
productCategory: "SomeCategory",
productDimensions: "SomeDimensions",
productCollection: "Some Collection",
productSoldBy: "??",
productPricing: ["X-Price = 100", "Y-Price = 200"]))
```

In my `viewDidLoad` I have:

```
sections =
[ProductSection(type: .ProductDetails,
items: [.Brand, .Collection, .Category, .Dimensions, .SoldBy]),
             ProductSection(type: .ProductPricing,
items: [.Pricing])]
```

In my `UITableViewDataSource` I have:

```
func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return sections.count
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return sections[section].items.count
    }
```

How do I impliment Pricing as a dynamic array in `viewDidLoad` & `UITableViewDataSource`?

**UPDATE:**

Here is my model of Product I've removed the other fields:

```
struct Product {
    let productPricing: [String]
etc.......

    var dictionary: [String : Any] {
        return [
etc.......
            "Pricing": productPricing
        ]
    }
}

extension Product: DocumentSerializable {
    init?(dictionary: [String : Any]) {
        guard let productCode = dictionary["Code"] as? String,
etc......
            let productPricing = dictionary["Pricing"] as? [String]
            else { return nil }

        self.init(productCode: productCode,
etc......
                  productPricing: productPricing)
    }
}
```

I simply have 5 static cells in one section and I have a second section with dynamic cells in.  Which is the best way to model this data?  Should I abandon my approach above?

Answer (score 0):

Make a struct to accommodate the api response.

```
struct Product: Codable {
  var productCode: String
  var productCategory: String
  ...
  var productPrice: [String] // or a other struct if only x and y prices are there.
  var productPrice: PPrice
}

struct PPrice {
   var XPrice: String
   var YPrice: String
}
```

And by making Item enum with `associated value` to accept the response.

```
enum Item {
   case Brand(String)
   case Collection(String)
   ...
   case Pricing([String]) or Pricing(PPrice) // in case of only x and y
}
```

Now for sections

```
extension Product {
  var detailsItems: [Item] {
     return [.Brand(self.productBrand), 
             .Collection(self.productCollection),...]
  }

  var priceItems: [Item] {
      return self.productPrice.map{.Price($0)}
      or 
      return [.Price(self.productPrice.XPrice),
              .Price(self.productPrice.YPrice)]
  }
}
```

This is a nice example of Swift enums with associated types as they are individual types bound with a case.

This also adds more safer and cleaner way to have more then single types of cells in tableView - collectionView data-sources.

Comment: Thanks, apologies I should of mentioned that Pricing section is dynamic so there could be any number of items in the array.

Comment: @DavidLintin is this solves your problem?, btw, this is a nice example of enum with associated values.

Comment: My problem is not with the data coming in.  My issue is inside my enum.  However, looking at your answer if I pass the Pricing case an array of string such as case Pricing([String]) It may work.  Will try and see.

Comment: I don't think this is the solution for me.  In simple terms I have 5 static cells in one section then another section with dynamic cells.

Comment: Sorry, i didn't get you, it would be nice if you can provide some more details about your configurations?.